# What should be the IP Address Requirement for App Service Creation?

Tags: azure, azure-appservice

We would like to create Azure App Service / Azure Function App resources for our new project and try to understand the IP Address Requirement. I am looking for this information so that I could allocate the subnet size accordingly.

Each App Service will just consume 1 App Address or More? I am new to App Service and haven't used the App Service before. So if someone could clarify in detail, it would be great.

I have created an App Service in our Virtual Network and I could see for Inbound Traffic one IP Address is Assigned and for Outbound, there are many IP Addresses assigned. So bit confused in allocating the IP Addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few IP addresses to be aware of in an App Service Environment. They are as follows:

- **Public inbound IP address:**  Used for external app traffic and management traffic in both internal and external deployments.
- **Outbound public IP:**  This is the IP address that is used as the "from" ip for connections that exit the virtual network. These connections do not go through a VPN.
- **Internal load balancer IP address:**  This address is solely used for internal purposes.
- **App-assigned IP-based TLS/SSL addresses:**  These addresses are only possible when using an external deployment and configuring IP-based TLS/SSL binding.

The App Service Environment UI in the Azure portal displays all of these IP addresses.

Please refer to these links as well for more information -
[IP addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/network-info#ip-addresses) ,
[App Service Environment networking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/networking#addresses)